# an application to Lax Milgram

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\Omega=(0,1)\times(0,1)$, $\Gamma_{1}=\{(x,y)\in \partial{\Omega}:y=0\}$, $\Gamma_{2}=\{(x,y)\in \partial{\Omega}:x=1\}$ and $V=\{u\in H^{1}(\Omega):u=0 on \Gamma_{2}\}$. Let $a(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \nabla v d\mu+\int_{\Gamma_{1}}5uvd\sigma$ and $l(v)=\int_{\Omega}8vd\mu+\int_{\Gamma_{1}}7vd\sigma$. I have to find the problem whose variational form is that. Also, I have to prove that there is only one element $u\in V$ that satisfies $a(u,.)=l$. For the first, my idea is to apply Lax Milgram lemma; I proved that both $a$ and $l$ are billinear, but I am stuck to prove that $a$ is coercitive and bounded. Could you give me any suggestion, please? For the second one, my idea is to apply Green theorem and to go back,but I dont know if it is a good idea. Can somebody help me? Thank you!! what "bothers" me are that integrals on $\Gamma_{1}$, which I dont know how to majore them to prove that a is bounded..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part see:
[lax milgram on a problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325987/lax-milgram-on-a-problem/2326049#2326049)

For the second suppose that $u$ and $v$ are regular enough within your domain $\Omega$ and integrate by parts to recover something similar to:
$$\int_{\Omega}(\mathcal{L}u-f)\,v\,dV=\int_{\partial \Omega/\Gamma}{\left(g(u)-\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\right)v\,d\sigma}$$
Suppose first $v\in D(\Omega)$ with $D$ a distribution space with compact support, therefore for almost all points of $\Omega$ you will have:
$$\mathcal{L}u=f \qquad in\, the \, sense \, of \, D'(\Omega) \tag{*}$$
You've recovered your PDE.

To recover the BCs take into account $(*)$ take $v$ arbitrary in $H^1(\Omega)$ and say that since $v$ is arbitrary the integrand needs to be 0 in $\partial\Omega/\Gamma$, and you recover the Neumann BCs
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=g(u) \qquad for\, almost \,all\,points\,in\,\partial\Omega/\Gamma $$
Finally you know that if $v=0$ in $\Gamma$ then $u=constant$.

Comment: Can you tell me, please, if I am doing well?

Comment: I wrote that if $a(u,v)=l(v)$, we have that:$\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \nabla v d\mu +\int_{\Gamma_{1}} 5uv d\sigma=\int_{\Omega}8vd\mu+\int_{\Gamma_{1}}7vd\sigma$; I appiled Greens' theorem and I obtained :

Comment: $-\int_{\Omega}\Delta u v+\int_{\partial \Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}v +\int_{\Gamma_{1}} 5uv=\int_{\Omega}8vd\mu+\int_{\Gamma_{1}}7v$; I tried to separate as you told me and we have that:$-\int_{\Omega}\Delta u v=\int_{\Omega}8vd\mu+\int_{\Gamma_{1}}(7-5u)v-\int_{\partial \Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}v$; now, how can I obtain the PDE?shall I develop the term with normal derivative?

Comment: Please join all the volume integrands under one integral sign, and all the boundary integrals under another. Then argue that you can choose $v\in D(\Omega)$ and therefore the integrals over the boundary $\partial \Omega$ vanish and you recover your PDE in the distributions sense. The unknown term that you mentioned is for the second part, when you recover your BCs.

Comment: So my PDE equations will be $-\Delta u =8$ on $\Omega$; am I right?

Comment: You are right Ramona

Comment: Ok!I understood now!! and now for the boundary conditions, I will have that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=7-5u$ on $\Gamma_{1}$?do I have any more boundary conditions?

Comment: Yes you have. You've determined only Robin BC in $\Gamma_1$. The rest of the boundary you have Dirichlet BC and therefore there $v=0$ and  $u=constant$. You are given in the problem  the value of such constant in $\Gamma_2$ which is $u=0$

Comment: Here is what I did not quite understand..why is u constant on the rest of the boundary?

Comment: When you transform the strong formulation into the weak one, you  can set $v=0$ in boundaries where the normal derivative of $u$ is not provided, i.e. where yu have Dirichlet BCs. Therefore such terms do not appear in the weak form but need to be imposed as a BCs for $u$ in the weak form. They are explicitly defined in your problem (not implicitly as yoour Robin BCs) and therefore you must not obtain them because they are already defined.

Comment: I understood!!Thank you very, very much!!